# Animate part of Activity Launch

Tags: android, android-activity

Is it possible to animate **part** of an activity launch?

I am not wanting my action bar to animate, however the rest of the view should slide in.

I have tried using a Gallery for this, however I have not been able to animate the gallery while programatically setting the selected view.  This is because the gallery does not load more than the currently displayed view and its immediate adjacent views.

Answer (score 0):

When you can use the viewflipper for this. Which shows 1 child at a time. You can set a IN and OUT animation for the views. So when you set the activew view index animations will be applied.